# Как называется плагин на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Нужно узнать какой плагин используется в хедере на сайте  **https://omoloko.icecream-chl.ru/**.Там где background-image приближается и отдаляется.

Comment: Там на css сделано, без jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это не плагин. Это обычная CSS анимация.

```css
.header {
  background: center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 170px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: height .35s;
}

.header.original {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.header__background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: zoom-background 15s infinite alternate linear;
  animation: zoom-background 15s infinite alternate linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom-background {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom-background {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5)
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header original" style="visibility: visible;">
  <div class="header__background" style="background-image: url(https://omoloko.icecream-chl.ru/images/omoloko/header_bg/6.jpg);"></div>
</header>
```

---

**Полезные ресурсы на эту тему**

- [CSS3-анимация](https://html5book.ru/css3-animation/)
- [Использование CSS-анимации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy)

Comment: Спасибо ,классная анимация.

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов, пожалуйста. Ну да, хотя и простая. Но морожено  захотелось)